# remove unsafe: from NSURL and load rest of URL webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I have a url like ***unsafe:customscheme://customResourceSpecifer***. I want to remove the unsafe prefix from it and load the rest of url, currently I am doing like this, is there any other way?

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if ([request.URL isUnsafeURL])
    {
        [self.webView loadRequest:[request.URL URLbyRemovingUnsafePrefix]];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Should you be calling `loadRequest` in that method?

Comment: so hat is the other solution?